# MySQL LIKE: Search for a keyword present into a text but not into html tags?

Tags: mysql

I want to fetch records in which a given keyword is present into the text but not present within any html tag.
Example with the keyword "span":

```html
Hello <span>world</span>
```

No, the keyword is only present into tags.

```html
Hello <span>world</span>, blah blah span blah blah
```

Ok, the keyword is present in the text.

This is what I have so far:

```sql
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE `content` LIKE '%span%' AND `content` NOT LIKE '<%span%>';
```

But it doesn't work.
What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

SQL's `LIKE` operator is truly not suitable for searching in a way that requires dealing with HTML tags. Whatever you do here will be brittle (prone to delivering bogus results).

That being said, try this.

```sql
SELECT * FROM mytable
 WHERE content LIKE '%span%'
   AND content NOT LIKE '%<span>%'   /* opening tag */
   AND content NOT LIKE '%</span>%'; /* closing tag */
```

As long as the `<span>` tags in your HTML are simple this might get you the results you want. But as soon as you have `<span id="spanid" class="text">` for a span tag, you can't use `LIKE` any more. The second `%` in `LIKE '%<span%>%'` matches everything in your HTML from the first `<span...>` up to the last closing tag.

You might consider using `RLIKE` and a regular expression. But those too are brittle.